# Ubuntu 17.10 how to disable favorites hotkey

Tags: shortcut-keys, workspaces, ubuntu-dock, favorites

Or possibly change it, my settings for switching workspaces ( I have static number set ) is Super+(1..N). Since upgrading to 17.10 whenever I use that combination it binds to the favorites on the side bar (aka Ubuntu Dock). Or in the case of Chrome where it has focus it shows thumbnails of the current windows.

This is really odd behavior which I'm assuming is a bug since there seems to be no place to override it and my mappings are clearly set still for switching workspaces which should have precedence over anything else.